# How to properly stop MySQL server on Mac OS X?

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x, mysqladmin, shutdown

I installed MySQL Community Server following instructions at

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/macosx-installation.html
```

with the Startup Item and the MySQL Preference Pane.

I can stop the server with

```
$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown 
Enter password:
$ ps aux | grep mysqld
.... grep mysqld
```

Is this the proper way?

Every time when I try to stop the sever using System Preference -> MySQL -> Stop MySQL Server, it hangs.  I will need to force quit the System Preference from the dock.  Any idea why the hang or how to find out?

Answer (score 2):

DISCLAIMER : Not a MacOS user

That is an alternative way. This shutdown method can be done in MacOS, Linux, Windows, any platform MySQL is supported in.

I actually prefer your mysqladmin method for a reason...

In Linux, I have seen the `mysql.sock` (the socket file) file just up and disappear without warning. The standard way to shutdown mysql in Linux is `service mysql stop`. Whenever the socket file disappears, the mysqld_safe program cannot shutdown without first seeing in the socket file. Such a standard shutdown would just hang.

I usually connect using TCP/IP

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -h127.0.0.1 -p shutdown
```

Doing it this way bypasses checking for a socket file. Of course, you must make sure root@127.0.0.1 exists. Run these lines to create that user:

```
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'whateverpassword';
```

CAVEAT If you do `DESC mysql.user;`, you will see that one of the privilege columns is `Shutdown_priv`. This evidently would permit a user who connects to mysqladmin to issue a shutdown. Users with this privilege cannot issue a shutdown from the mysql client. Users with shutdown_priv='Y' can only be done from mysqladmin.

Comment: When you `man service` in Mac OS X 10.6.8, you can see that `service is deprecated and will be removed in a future release of Mac OS X.`

Comment: how can it be start it by console?